# C Text Processing: Output Wrong Size

Tags: c, arrays, text

I'm writing ac program that takes a text file of words, and copies only words without capitalization or punctuation, and which are 4 or more characters long.  I have tested the boolean functions  int containsPunctuationOrCaps(char *word) and int longerThanThree(char *word) , and they both work.  However, my main function only prints words of at least seven characters, and anything longer is truncated.

```
int main() {
  char *currentWord = malloc(36);
  int count = 0;
  char *Words[3000];
  FILE *fin, *fout;

  fin = fopen(INFILE,"r");
  if (fin==NULL) {
    printf("INPUT FILE NOT FOUND\n");
    return 1;
  } 
  while(fgets(currentWord, sizeof(currentWord), fin) != NULL) {
    if(!containsPunctuationOrCaps(currentWord) && longerThanThree(currentWord)) {
    Words[count]=currentWord;
    printf("%s\n",currentWord);
    count++;
    }
  }
  fclose(fin);    
}
```

When I change 
     char *currentWord = malloc(36);
to 
    char currentWord[];
it doesn't read anything.  How do I make this work?

Comment: `sizeof(currentWord)` is `sizeof(char *)` which happens to be 8 on your machine.

Comment: Thank you, you're right.  But why doesn't it accept smaller input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `currentWord` as a `char *`, which points to dynamically allocated memory. `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time, and evaluates to the size (in bytes) required by the *type of* `currentWord` - in your case, the size required to store a memory address/pointer, which apparently is 8 bytes on your system. Since `fgets` appends a terminating `\0` byte, the `fgets` call only reads 7 characters.

You could replace `char *currentWord = malloc(36);` (note: you never `free` the allocated memory) by `char currentWord[36];`, that should lead to at least 35 characters being read. However, `fgets` always attempts to read until the end of the line (or until the buffer is full), hence the `currentWord` array will contain multiple words.

You could split the `currentWord` at spaces, but that requires additional checking logic at the end of the buffer (is the end of `currentWord` the end of a word/the line, or was the buffer just full and the word continues?). The easiest way to accomplish what you want would probably be to read the file character-by-character (using [`getc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getc.3.html), but you should ensure that you use buffered I/O, see [`setbuf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html)). As you read each character, you check if it is a word or non-word character (or EOF). In the former case, you append to the buffer, while in the latter case you output the word if it meets your criteria, first however appending a `\0` terminator. The `currentWord` buffer should be dynamically allocated (unless you know a definite upper bound of word lengths), and you might have to reallocate it if the word currently being read is longer than the allocated memory can hold.

Comment: Thank you; I didn't realize sizeof() was evaluated at compile time.  Now I have a different problem though: I changed to currentWord[36] and now it will not read anything. This word list is separated by newlines, not spaces, by the way.

Comment: What does it mean, it doesn't print anything? Is the buffer empty, or is every word filtered out by your if condition? Also note that `fgets` adds the line termination characters to the buffer!
By the way, the line `Words[count]=currentWord;` won't work as expected - it only stores the address of the local array variable `currentWord` in the `Words` array, which is the same for every line and overwritten in each iteration. `Words[count] = strdup(currentWord)` should work (note that this allocates memory which should later be `free`d).

Comment: You were right; it was my punctuation filter that was failing because it counted newlines.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
char currentWord[];
```

instead of

```
char *currentWord = malloc(36);
```

you declare an 0-sized static array of chars. When sizeof is applied to the name of a static array, the result is the size in bytes of that array.

For example, in this case:

```
char currentWord[10];
```

sizeof would have returned 10*sizeof(char).

In your case, the array is empty, therefore sizeof(currentWord) will return 0.